# How can I split LaTeX source line into multiple lines?

Tags: sourcecode

I want to split LaTeX source line

```
Some text I would like to have in one line~\footnote{
  something explained
}
```

into something like:

```
Some text I would like to have in one line\
~\footnote{
  something explained
}
```

but compiling to the same output.  Is there any way to instruct LaTeX to just ignore the newline character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A newline is the same as a space so you can split anywhere that you have a space, or you can comment out the newline with `%`

You show the original as

```
Some text I would like to have in one line~\footnote{
  something explained
}
```

Which already has two newlines being used as possibly spurious spaces (you are relying on `\footnote` to trim the spaces which will not be true of all commands. I would write it as

```
Some text I would like to have in one line~\footnote{%
  something explained%
}
```

(except I would not have a `~` before the footnote marker, but that's a style choice not a text question)

so you could have any of

```
Some text I would like to have in one line%
~\footnote{%
  something explained%
}
```

or

```
Some text I would like to have in one line%
~\footnote
  {something explained}
```

or

```
Some text I would like to have in one line~\footnote
  {something explained}
```

etc